# SSH user client config with host wildcards

Tags: 14.04, ssh, configuration

I have this in my ~/.ssh/config file:

```
Host jupiter
  HostName jupiter.engin.x.edu
  User rob

Host *.engin.x.edu
  User bladex
```

Local user is 'rob' and I want to use the username 'bladex' for every host in the engin.x.edu sub-domain. But this isn't working, typing "ssh host.engin.x.edu" responds with "rob@host.engin.x.edu's password:"

What am I doing wrong? My resolv.conf includes "search engin.x.edu".

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times that `ssh` ignores a file, that's because file permissions are wrong.

For example, `man ssh_config` says:

> ~/.ssh/config
>
> This is the per-user configuration file.  The format of this file is described above.  This file is used by the SSH client.  Because of the potential for abuse, this file must have strict permissions: read/write for the user, and not accessible by others. It may be group-writable provided that the group in question contains only the user.

You must also check the permissions of all the parent directories of the file. I.e., if your home is `/home/rob`, you should check the permissions of `/home`, `/home/rob`, `/home/rob/.ssh`, and `/home/rob/.ssh/config`.

Assuming that your home has already secure permissions, a command that often helps is:

```
chmod -R go= ~/.ssh
```

Remember that `ssh -vvv host.engin.x.edu` it useful to debug those problems.

Comment: I checked permissions, and the config file was 640, so I set it to 600. Everything else is ok. ssh -vvv shows that the only wildcard match is '*' which comes from the one at /etc/ssh/ssh_config